# Creating a summary table on BigQuery aggregating multiple values in one row

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to create a table like below, aggregating by payment method, where I can see a summary of the combinations of services used in one day. In this case, combinations (A, B) in service_type would be the same as (B, A), and (A, A, C) would be the same as (A, C). I need to use BigQuery, and I don't know how to generate all the combinations for service_type without manually printing them out. no_of_service is the number of services grouped in service_type, and total_orders is the number of unique customer_ids which purchased that specific combination of orders in that date.

```
order_date  no_of_service  service_type  total_orders  order_payment
2018-04-03      1               A              5            CASH
2018-04-03      1               B              4            CASH
2018-04-03      1               C              1            CASH
2018-04-03      1               D              10           CASH
2018-04-03      1               E              5            CASH
2018-04-03      3               A,C,D          10           CREDIT
2018-04-03      3               B,D,E          5            CREDIT
2018-04-02      1               A              8            CREDIT
2018-04-02      1               C              7            CREDIT
```

The daily_order table which I'm querying from has the columns **order_payment** (CASH, CREDIT, etc), **service_type** (A, B, C, etc), **customer_id** (unique value for each customer), and **order_time** (e.g. 2018-04-06 15:06:26 UTC). It looks like this:

```
order payment  service_type  customer_id  order_time
CASH           A             58128        2018-04-06 15:06:26 UTC
CREDIT         B             58256        2018-04-06 15:08:34 UTC
```

Comment: Show us some sample data and its matching expected result. All as formatted text, not images (or links to images.) Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve too.

Comment: added some more info, hope it's helpful!

Comment: Is that sample table data or the expected result? We need both.

Comment: Sorry about that, added more info!